# The Labels in my code written in KIVY do not update

Tags: python, kivy, label

I have tried all possible code variations and even gone through the documentation of Kivy but I just cannot manage to get my labels to update from inside a loop. The code is att below. Please can someone help me?!

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import threading
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from api_helper import ShoonyaApiPy
import logging
import pyotp
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time, date, datetime
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile
import os
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        spacing:50
        padding:(10,10,10,10)
        Label:
            text: 'OPTIONS: SHORT STRADDLE STRATEGY 1 '
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:40
            background_color:(1,1,1,1)
        Button:
            text: 'LOGIN '
            size_hint:(1,0.5)
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20
            background_color:(0,1,1,1)
            on_press: root.login()
        Button:
            text: 'INITIATE & MANAGE POSITIONS '
            size_hint:(1,0.5)
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20
            background_color:(0,1,0,1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'initiateposn'
        Button:
            text: 'MANAGE EXISTING POSITIONS '
            size_hint:(1,0.5)
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20
            background_color:(0,0,1,1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'manageposn'
        Button:
            text: 'LOGOUT '
            size_hint:(1,0.5)
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press: root.logout()

<InitiateposnScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        spacing:50
        padding:(10,10,10,10)        
        qty:qty
                    
        Label:
            text: 'INITIATE & MANAGE POSNS! '
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:25            
        Label:
            text: 'ENTER THE QTY OF LOTS (EG 1 / 2 / 3 etc.) :' 
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20        
        TextInput:
            id: qty
            multiline:False  
        Label:
            text: 'TAKE PROFIT @ (ENTER O FOR STD 1800) :' 
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20        
        TextInput:
            id: profit
            multiline:False           
        Button:
            text: 'INITIATE NEW POSITION(S)'
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20
            background_color:(0,0,1,1)
            on_press: root.initiate_posn()
        Label:
            id: posn_status
            text: root.status1
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:25          
        Button:
            text: 'MAIN MENU'
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20     
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
                    
<ManageposnScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        spacing:50
        padding:(10,10,10,10)
                    
        Label:
            text: 'MANAGE EXISTING POSITIONS ONLY '
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:40 
        Label:
            text: 'TAKE PROFIT @ (ENTER O FOR STD 1800) :' 
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20        
        TextInput:
            id: profit2
            multiline:False           
        Button:
            text: 'MANAGE MY POSITION(S)'
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20
            background_color:(0,0,1,1)
            on_press: root.manage_posn()
        Label:
            id: posn_status2
            text: root.status2
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:25          
        Button:
            text: 'MAIN MENU'
            font_name: 'calibri'
            font_size:20
            background_color:(1,0,0,1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")

# broker api
api = ShoonyaApiPy()
call_sell_instr = ""
put_sell_instr =""

def sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, qty, c, p):

   pass

def current_pnl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list, c, p):
    pass

def trailing_sl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, t_sl_count, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list, c, p):
    pass
    
    return True

def fixed_sl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, t_sl_count, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list, c, p):
    pass
    
             
def delete_file(file_path):
    try:
        os.remove(file_path)
        print(f"File {file_path} deleted successfully.")
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"Error deleting file {file_path}: {e}")

def get_time(time_string):
    data = time.strptime(time_string,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    return time.mktime(data)

def closest_to_nearest_50(number):
    pass

# master scrip list
def open_text_file_from_zip(url):
    pass

# File path for current trades
file_path = "C:\\path\\current_trades.txt"
unreal_pnl_list = []
c=0
p=0


# Declare the screens

class MenuScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def login(self):
        
        #credentials

        #make the api call
        ret = api.login(userid=user, password=pwd, twoFA=pyotp.TOTP(token).now(), vendor_code=vc, api_secret=apikey, imei=imei)

        if (ret):
            layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)

            loginLabel = Label(text="You have logged in Successfully!")
            closeButton = Button(text="OK")

            layout.add_widget(loginLabel)
            layout.add_widget(closeButton)

            popup = Popup(title = 'Login Successful!', content=layout, size_hint=(None,None), size=(300,200))
            popup.open()

            closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)

    def logout(self):
        api = ShoonyaApiPy()
        #credentials

        #make the api call
        ret = api.login(userid=user, password=pwd, twoFA=pyotp.TOTP(token).now(), vendor_code=vc, api_secret=apikey, imei=imei)
        if (ret):
            api.logout()

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)

        loginLabel = Label(text="You have logged out Successfully!")
        closeButton2 = Button(text="OK")

        layout.add_widget(loginLabel)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton2)

        popup = Popup(title = 'Logout Successful!', content=layout, size_hint=(None,None), size=(300,200))
        popup.open()

        closeButton2.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)

        App.get_running_app().stop()
        


class InitiateposnScreen(Screen):
    status1 = StringProperty()
    qty = ObjectProperty(None)
    profit = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InitiateposnScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.status1 = ' **STATUS OF POSN** '

    def update_label(self, unreal_pnl):
        self.status1 = f'Unrealized PNL : {unreal_pnl} !'
   
    def update_thread(self, unreal_pnl):
        threading.Thread(target=self.update_label(unreal_pnl)).start()

    def initiate_posn(self):
        qty_value = self.ids.qty.text
        qty = int(qty_value) * 50
        profit = self.ids.profit.text
        take_profit = int(profit)

        # master scrip list
        url = "https://api.shoonya.com/NFO_symbols.txt.zip"
        open_text_file_from_zip(url)

        scrip_list = pd.read_csv("N:\\Programming_Wks\\PythonInVSC\\Trading\\Algo Trade Finvasia\\ShoonyaApi-py-master\\local_file.txt", delimiter=',', header=0) 

        df = scrip_list[(scrip_list.Exchange == 'NFO') & (scrip_list.Symbol == 'NIFTY') & (scrip_list.Instrument == 'OPTIDX')]
        sorted_exp_dates = sorted(pd.to_datetime(df['Expiry']).dt.date.unique())
        
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)

        loginLabel = Label(text=f"Some Text")
        closeButton = Button(text="OK")

        layout.add_widget(loginLabel)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)

        popup = Popup(title = 'Position Initiated!', content=layout, size_hint=(None,None), size=(700,200))
        popup.open()

        closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)

        call -= 20
        put += 50
        count =0
        t_sl_count =0

        while (count==0):
            
            # if (datetime.now().time() >= time(16,5)):
                # count+=1
    
            nifty = float(api.get_quotes('NSE', '26000')['lp'])
            # print(f'NIFTY LTP is   : {nifty} !')

            c=1
            p=1

            unreal_pnl = current_pnl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list,c,p)
            # print(f'Unrealized PNL : {unreal_pnl} !')

            # self.ids.posn_status.text = f'Unrealized PNL : {unreal_pnl} !'
            self.update_thread(unreal_pnl)

            if (unreal_pnl>=take_profit):
                
                if (trailing_sl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, t_sl_count, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list,c,p)):
                    
                    sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                    count+=1

                    # Call the function to delete the file
                    delete_file(file_path)

            if (nifty <= put):
                c=0
                p=1
                sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                if (fixed_sl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, t_sl_count, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list,c,p)):
                    c=1
                    p=0
                    sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                    count+=1

                    # Call the function to delete the file
                    delete_file(file_path)
            
            if (nifty >= call):
                c=1
                p=0
                sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                if (fixed_sl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, t_sl_count, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list,c,p)):
                    c=0
                    p=1
                    sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                    count+=1

                    # Call the function to delete the file
                    delete_file(file_path)

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)

        loginLabel = Label(text=" Positions Closed! ")
        closeButton = Button(text="OK")

        layout.add_widget(loginLabel)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)

        popup = Popup(title = 'Position Closed!', content=layout, size_hint=(None,None), size=(400,200))
        popup.open()

        closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
        # self.add_widget(Label(text=f'SELL ORDERS FOR X PE AND Y CE PLACED FOR {qty_value} LOTS!', color = (1,0,0,1)))
        # self.ids.qty.text = ''                             

class ManageposnScreen(Screen):
    status2 = StringProperty()
    profit = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ManageposnScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.status2 = ' **STATUS OF POSN** '

    def update_label(self, unreal_pnl):
        self.status1 = f'Unrealized PNL : {unreal_pnl} !'
   
    def update_thread(self, unreal_pnl):
        threading.Thread(target=self.update_label(unreal_pnl)).start()

    def manage_posn(self):
        
        profit = self.ids.profit2.text
        take_profit = int(profit)
        ret = api.get_trade_book()

        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            # Open the current trades file in read mode ('r')
            with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
                # Read the values from the file
                lines = file.readlines()
                
                # Extract values from the lines
                call = lines[0].strip()  # Remove newline characters
                put = lines[1].strip()
                call_sell_instr = lines[2].strip()
                put_sell_instr = lines[3].strip()
                qty = lines[4].strip()
                sell_call_value = lines[5].strip()
                sell_put_value = lines[6].strip()
            
        call_check = float(call) - 20
        put_check = float(put) + 50
        count =0
        t_sl_count = 0

        while (count==0):
            
            # if (datetime.now().time() >= time(16,5)):
            #     count+=1
    
            nifty = float(api.get_quotes('NSE', '26000')['lp'])
            # print(f'NIFTY LTP is   : {nifty} !')

            c=1
            p=1

            unreal_pnl = current_pnl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list,c,p)
            # print(f'Unrealized PNL : {unreal_pnl} !')
        
            self.update_thread(unreal_pnl)
            # self.ids.posn_status2.text = f'Unrealized PNL : {unreal_pnl} !'
            # self.ids.update_label2.text = f'{datetime.now().time()} :: NIFTY LTP : {nifty} :: Unrealized PNL : {unreal_pnl}'

            if (unreal_pnl>=take_profit):
                
                if (trailing_sl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, t_sl_count, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list,c,p)):
                    
                    sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                    count+=1

                    # Call the function to delete the file
                    delete_file(file_path)

            if (nifty <= put_check):
                c=0
                p=1
                sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                if (fixed_sl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, t_sl_count, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list,c,p)):
                    c=1
                    p=0
                    sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                    count+=1

                    # Call the function to delete the file
                    delete_file(file_path)
            
            if (nifty >= call_check):
                c=1
                p=0
                sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                if (fixed_sl(call_sell_instr, put_sell_instr, t_sl_count, sell_call_value, sell_put_value, qty, unreal_pnl_list,c,p)):
                    c=0
                    p=1
                    sq_off_buy(call_sell_instr,put_sell_instr,qty,c,p)

                    count+=1

                    # Call the function to delete the file
                    delete_file(file_path)   

        
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)

        loginLabel = Label(text=" Positions Closed! ")
        closeButton = Button(text="OK")

        layout.add_widget(loginLabel)
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)

        popup = Popup(title = 'Positions Closed!', content=layout, size_hint=(None,None), size=(400,200))
        popup.open()  
        closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)                     


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # Create the screen manager
        sm = ScreenManager()

        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(InitiateposnScreen(name='initiateposn'))
        sm.add_widget(ManageposnScreen(name='manageposn'))

        # screens = [Screen(name='Page {}'.format(i)) for i in range (3)]
        # sm.switch_to(screens[0])
        # sm.switch_to(screens[1])
        # sm.switch_to(screens[2])
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I am trying to update the momentary profit or loss after calculations in my label normally using code: 'self.ids.posn_status2.text = f'Unrealized PNL : {unreal_pnl} !' and then by using new thread : 'self.update_thread(unreal_pnl)'. However, the label does not update at all!

Comment: The basics of Kivy Gui is that the GUI (including Label texts) are only updated on the main thread. If your loop is running on the main thread, the Labels cannot be updated until your loop completes and releases the main thread. The normal approach to this issue is to execute your loop in another thread and to use `Clock.schedule_once()` to do the Label updates back on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am new to coding in kivy, and will greatly appreciate if you could illustrate this solution with a small example. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of using `threading` and updating a `Label` from that thread:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: lab
        text: '0'
    Button:
        text: 'Start Thread'
        on_release: app.doit()
'''


class UseThreadingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def doit(self):
        # start long running loop in another thread thread
        threading.Thread(target=self.long_loop, daemon=True).start()

    def long_loop(self):
        # this is running in a separate thread
        for i in range(100):
            # do some time consuming work here
            sleep(1)
            # schedule label update to run in main thread
            Clock.schedule_once(self.update_label)

    def update_label(self, _dt):
        # this runs on the main thread
        label = self.root.ids.lab
        label.text = str(int(label.text) + 1)

UseThreadingApp().run()
```

A small variation of this uses the `mainthread` decorator instead of `Clock.schedule_once()`, but they are essentially equivalent. To do that add the decorator to the `update_label()` method:

```
@mainthread
def update_label(self):
    # this runs on the main thread
    label = self.root.ids.lab
    label.text = str(int(label.text) + 1)
```

Note removal of the `_dt` argument.

Then the loop becomes:

```
def long_loop(self):
    # this is running in a separate thread
    for i in range(100):
        # do some time consuming work here
        sleep(1)
        self.update_label()
```